# Remove Element from Rust BTreeMap that was Previously Found

Tags: rust

I woule like to remove an element from rust `BTreeMap` that I previouly found using a key.

I made up a toy example for this. Suppose I have a `BTreeMap` that tracks all active bank accounts (i.e. accounts with balance >=0). I charge a fee on a specific account, and if the remaining balance after fee is negative, the account is removed from the map.

The following is a working sample:

```rust
use std::collections::BTreeMap;
use std::env;

struct BankAccount {
    balance: i32
}

fn charge_fee(
    active_accounts: &mut BTreeMap<u32, BankAccount>, acct_id: u32, fee: i32) {
    if let Some(tmp) = active_accounts.get_mut(&acct_id) {
        (*tmp).balance -= fee;
        if (*tmp).balance<0 {
            active_accounts.remove(&acct_id);
        }
    }
}

fn test_charge_fee(account_id: u32, fees: i32) {
    let mut active_accounts = BTreeMap::new();
    active_accounts.insert(0, BankAccount{balance: 100});
    active_accounts.insert(1, BankAccount{balance: 50});
    active_accounts.insert(2, BankAccount{balance: 29});
    active_accounts.insert(3, BankAccount{balance: 87});

    println!("Active accts before charging fees:");
    for (k, v) in active_accounts.iter() {
        println!("{}: {}", k, v.balance);
    }

    charge_fee(&mut active_accounts, account_id, fees);

    println!("Active accts after charging fees:");
    for (k, v) in active_accounts.iter() {
        println!("{}: {}", k, v.balance);
    }
}
```

`BTreeMap::remove` will always perform a key search throught the entire tree, which is an unecessary cost if the key has recently been found using `BTreeMap::get_mut` or `BTreeMap::get`. It could have started just from the node where the key was found.

My questions are as folows:

1. Is there a nice way to remove the key-value pair from the tree without paying this cost?
2. Is `BTreeMap` the best container type for this type of application? Any suggestions for alternatives?
3. Did I make any mistakes?

Comment: instead of using `remove(&acct_id)`, what about `remove_entry(&tmp)`?

Comment: @Claies `remove_entry()` just returns the key too, it is not different than `remove()`.

Comment: The first question is on topic. The second will be if you will describe how you measure "best". The third is off topic here. But asking three questions at once is also not allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [the entry API](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.BTreeMap.html#method.entry):

```rust
fn charge_fee(active_accounts: &mut BTreeMap<u32, BankAccount>, acct_id: u32, fee: i32) {
    if let std::collections::btree_map::Entry::Occupied(mut entry) = active_accounts.entry(acct_id)
    {
        let tmp = entry.get_mut();
        tmp.balance -= fee;
        if tmp.balance < 0 {
            entry.remove();
        }
    }
}
```